# i have visual studio error debug assertion failed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dynamic-memory-allocation

In visual studio program crashes: error debug assertion failed. What is wrong in my code? There is no syntax errors. Only warning: **deletion of array expression,conversion to pointer suplied** When i run it with cmd standart compiler it works fine.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define max_size 100

class my_array{
    int* arr[max_size];
public:
    my_array() {}
    my_array(int size) {
        if (size <= 0 || size > max_size) {
            exit(1);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            arr[i] = new int;
            cout << "Enter element [" << i + 1 << "] = ";
            cin >> *arr[i];
        }
    }
    ~my_array() {
        delete[] arr;
    }
    void operator[](int n) {
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cout << "Enter element [" << i << "] = " << *arr[i] << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    my_array array(6);
    array[5];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior due to `delete[] arr;` in `~my_array()`. `arr` was never allocated with `new`, hence it should not be deleted with `delete`.

Comment: And this is very fishy: `arr[i] = new int;`. What are you trying to achieve? You have an array of pointers to `int`, each of them pointing to a single `int`. This isn't efficient, neither in terms of speed, memory usage and simplicity.

Comment: so how to allocate array in constructor ?

Comment: @MateGvenetadze You shouldnt need to allocate in the constructor, just use `int arr[max_size];`, this way, you also don't have to delete anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are deleting `arr` here:

```
delete[] arr;
```

while `arr` has never been allocated by `new`. In your original program `arr` is a fixed size array of pointers to `int`.

You probably want this:

```
class my_array {
  int *arr;
public:
  my_array() {}
  my_array(int size) {
    if (size <= 0 || size > max_size) {  // BTW this test isn't really necessary, as we
                                         // can allocate as much memory as available
                                         // anyway much more than just 100
      exit(1);
    }

    arr = new int[size];         // allocate array of size size
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      cout << "Enter element [" << i + 1 << "] = ";
      cin >> arr[i];
    }
  }

  ~my_array() {
    delete[] arr;                // delete array allocated previously
  }

  void operator[](int n) {
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      cout << "Enter element [" << i << "] = " << arr[i] << endl;
    }
  }
};
```

Instead of having a fixed size array of pointers to int, you have a dynamic array of `int`s.

There is still room for improvement though. For example the `my_array()` constructor is pointless here, And it's odd to use the `[]` operator for printing the content, and the text `"Enter element ["` in the `[]` operator is also questionable.

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what i wanted

Comment: I have no idea i pressed ^

Comment: @MateGvenetadze yes, but someone else pressed the "down" arrow.